# Xamarin trial - apps built there lost forever if I don't upgrade?

Tags: xamarin

I'm pretty tempted to try out Xamarin. Particularly within Visual Studio. But as this is for non-commercial experimentation only, at least for now, I don't really see myself ever acquiring a license. As such: Will any progress I have made be lost after the trial period ends? The [Xamarin website](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/beginning_a_xamarin_trial/) has this to say:

> Apps built in trial mode can only be run within a 24 hour window after
>   they are built, and bear a splash screen that indicates they were
>   built using the Trial SDK. The Xamarin Trial is licensed for
>   evaluation purposes only.

But I should be able to re-use the code etc in other products, right? Or should I be looking at free alternatives from the get-go?

Answer (score 1):

The code you write is yours and you can do whatever you want with it.

You just won't be able to use an apps/executables you've built from your source code after 24h.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I worded that a bit poorly. Will my code from Xamarin be adopted to their framework, leaving me with lots of work to translate it to other tools? Or will I be able to re-use the code as-is?

Comment: Which other tool are you thinking of? If you're considering using native tools (Xcode on iOS, Eclipse on Android), have in mind that you'd be writing C#, so none of that code would be usable in neither Xcode nor Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not too read-up on what the best alternatives are, but from what I understand, there are other cross-platform tools similar to Xamarin. No idea of how could they might be, though. If Xamarin is the only viable C# solution, then obviously the entire point is moot.

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic code is written in plain C# not includes any platform specific code(eg. using Android API) and shared,then you must be able to use that code to any other .NET framework using C#.Although you can use `Xamarin Studio`,if it expires you can continue with `starter Edition`.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016 Visual Studio Community edition includes full Xamarin support for free. You can publish whatever you want and there is no limitation on screens, etc...